# Toggle padding of a <h1> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I've got one h1 tag and two buttons:

```
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
<input id="button2" type="submit" name="button" value="enter2"/>
```

Is there a better (or just shorter) way to do this:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('h1').css('padding-left', '50px')
    $('#button').css('display', 'none')
    $('#button2').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#button2').on('click', function(){
    $('h1').css('padding-left', '0px')
    $('#button').css('display', 'block')
    $('#button2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Note : **Maybe I don't need two buttons but only one?**

Comment: Since you are changing separate elements I don't think there is a shorter way to do this. You could apply a class to a parent element and use descendant selectors, though.

Comment: Best way is to add class to parent element and use css to do the css changes. You could just have 1 button and toggle the class on the parent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try,

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('h1').css('padding-left', function(_,val){
       return parseInt(val,10) == 0 ? 50 : 0;
    })
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7ctzq/)

Comment: You should be using `"50px"` instead of just `50`. (Not the downvoter BTW).

Comment: Does jQuery auto-correct it? I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: @RoToRa `$( "div.example" ).css( "width", function( index ) {
  return index * 50;
});`  This is an example code i found in the DOC. And look at the value argument's permissible type. http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value Number is also there..

Answer (score 1):

Or just have the padding in a css class and toggle the class on the `h1`.

**Html:**

```
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
```

**Css:**

```
h1.withPadding {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

**Js:**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('h1').toggleClass('withPadding');
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb3g4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**HTML :**

```
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
```

**Css :**

```
.active {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

**Js :**

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('h1').toggleClass('active');
})
```